# CLR sql procedure not visible in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, sqlclr

project I am currently working in, has posed a need to implement portion of business logic in CLR stored procedure in Visual Studio 2010. Once I create it, I successfully deploy it to SQL Server, and am able to use it in SQL Server Management Studio.

However, once I try to add the same stored procedure in Crystal Report (Crystal Report XI), 
I do not see it in the list of available stored procedures of selected database.
All other, 'standard' t-sql stored procedures are visible.

Is there some kind of security attribute, or what not, I need to enable?

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to `GRANT EXEC ON <<procedure>> TO <<role>>`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. I just granted exec for it to public, and I still do not see it in the list of stored procedures for the database.